# bash: sudo: command not found on GoDaddy server

Tags: linux, ssh, web-deployment, sudo

I want to deploy a node app on the GoDaddy server but when I access it through ssh access or Cpanel terminal it gives me the same error

```
    bash: sudo: command not found
```

Comment: Have you checked the GoDaddy portal? Have you tried to google before asking the question here? Check this out - https://in.godaddy.com/community/GoDaddy-Web-Hosting/bash-sudo-command-not-found/td-p/19690

Answer (score 0):

simply type in your terminal
"ssh root@[GoDaddy IP]"
You should be prompted for a password and a bash will automatically be opened. On root you dont need sudo.